# receive file in my xamarin app from another's app share function

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

How to receive file in my xamarin app from another's app share function?

```cs
if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend)
{
    {
        // This is just an example of the data stored in the extras 
        var uriFromExtras = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream) asAndroid.Net.Uri;
        var subject = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject);

        // Get the info from ClipData 
        var pdf = Intent.ClipData.GetItemAt(0);

        // Open a stream from the URI 
        var pdfStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(pdf.Uri);

        // Save it over 
        var memOfPdf = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        pdfStream.CopyTo(memOfPdf);
        var docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPat(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docsPath, "temp.pdf");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memOfPdf.ToArray());

        mainForms.DisplayThePDF(filePath);
    }
}
```

this is only for PDF and also not working well.

Comment: `this is only for PDF and also not working well.` What exactly is the problem? Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: I need to create a Xamarin app that can perform the following: 
1. Open Image Gallery on Android
2. Select any image and share
3. Share should display the name of our Xamarin app
4. On selecting our app's icon
5. Our app should be opened and it should display this shared image.

I am able to do till step 4. After selecting my app's icon, my app opens up but I am not able to receive the shared image.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo to github or onedriver you have achieved so that we can test on our side?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16fTy7roNLc0MWbNOu_tJL4RjJws0vOig/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: From this above mentioned link you can download that demo and can test on your side too!!                                                                                                                                  After run this above Xamarin code you will able to see tasks to perform after that.